# Validate a name in Python

Tags: python, regex

For an internationalised project, I have to validate the global syntax for a name (first, last) with Python. But the lack of unicode classes support is really maling things harder.

Is there any regex / library to do that ?

Examples:

Björn, Anne-Charlotte, توماس, 毛, or מיק must be accepted.
-Björn, Anne--Charlotte, Tom_ or entries like that *should* be rejected.

Is there any simple way to do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the global syntax for a name? Are you saying that there is an ANSI standard for this?

Comment: What exact do you want to test? If the name is a correct name or that it contains only letters from the alphabets?

Comment: In general, if you do this you will disallow real names. see http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Nope, no standard, just logic. A name must not contain arobases, hyphens, dashes or other punctuation characters. But yep, I'm basically trying to match letters from emery alphabet supported in unicode, just like the \p{Letter} in perl.

Comment: You'd better think at least twice before using any regex since it can be extremely annoying if one typed his/her real name and then got a message "illegal name".

Comment: I understand your point. My client just gave me specifications to follow, I'll follow them. I'll think a little more about it =)

Comment: Nikolai Rimsky-Korsakov is not happy with the hyphen rule.  Patrick O'Brian really wants apostrophes.  Adela Rogers St. Johns needs "." in her name.  Not sure how you can reject "punctuation".

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The hyphen rule was not relevant. I updated the regex to `^[^\W0-9_]+\.?([ \-'‧][^\W0-9_]+\.?)*?$` in order to accept each one of your examples, and every other example I could find.

Comment: @Pierre: You'll be disappointed.  Wait until you start trying to process real names.  About the only rational rule is that some punctuation marks `!@#$%^&*():<>` are unlikely.  But almost everything else will actually occur.    Marisa de los Santos in particular and Antoine de Saint-Exupéry have odd upper-case lowercase rules, don't they?

Comment: I agree with you. But as I said, I'm not the one who decides, and my client _wants_ a regex validation as much limitative as possible. I submitted your point of view, anyway. For the record, the two names you gave me are valid with the regex I proposed. Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: Never mind the regex problems ... "name (first, last)" is already a FAIL. cf "J. Edgar Hoover", "S. John Machin", "Mao Tse-Tung" aka "Mao Tse Tung" aka "Mao Zedong", "Sukarno", "Kovacs Laszlo", etc

Comment: @Pierre: For the record, "I'm not the one who decides" is a bad idea, also.  You do, indeed, decide.  You can implement as much or as little of a vague requirement as you see fit.  You've decided on some rules.  You.  Not your customer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Python does support unicode in regular expressions if you specify the [re.UNICODE](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.U) flag. You can probably use something like this:

```
r'^[^\W_]+(-[^\W_]+)?$'
```

Test code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

names = [
            u'Björn',
            u'Anne-Charlotte',
            u'توماس',
            u'毛',
            u'מיק',
            u'-Björn',
            u'Anne--Charlotte',
            u'Tom_',
        ]

for name in names:
    regex = re.compile(r'^[^\W_]+(-[^\W_]+)?$', re.U)
    print u'{0:20} {1}'.format(name, regex.match(name) is not None)
```

Result:

```
Björn                True
Anne-Charlotte       True
توماس                True
毛                    True
מיק                  True
-Björn               False
Anne--Charlotte      False
Tom_                 False
```

If you also want to disallow digits in names then change `[^\W_]` to `[^\W\d_]` in both places.

Comment: You might want to add a space to the allowed characters though.

Comment: Modified to `^[^\W0-9_]+([ \-'‧][^\W0-9_]+)*?$`, to support the most names. Will be tested as extensively as possible. Thanks a lot =)

Comment: @Pierre: Use `\Z`, not `$`, otherwise "Fred\n" will be regarded as valid. Perhaps you are assuming that the input has already been sanitised to the extent of stripping leading and trailing whitespace and replacing all internal runs of whitespace by a single space. `\d` as suggested by Mark is NOT the same as `0-9` ... is your change deliberate?

Comment: Note: This still isn't perfect, as it will also match things like `fjdkghkjsdhfsqjkqsd`, which will probably never be a valid first name anywhere.